# How can I have a "generic" delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

My current situation looks like this:

I have these two delegates in a separate file:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(Object obj, EventArgs e); 
public delegate void OtherEventHandler(Object obj, OtherEventArgs e);
```

I have an `Event` class that look like this:

```
class Event {
   EventHandler _handler;
   public Event(EventHandler handler) {
      _handler = handler;
   }
}
```

I have another class that inherits `Event` this way:

```
class OtherEvent : Event {
   OtherEventHandler _handler;
   public OtherEvent (OtherEventHandler handler) : base(handler) {
      _handler = handler;
   }
}
```

This one is where the problem occurs. The error is with the part on `base(handler)`. Because `handler` in `OtherEvent` is an `OtherEventHandler`, the base class cannot accept it; the base class only accepts `EventHandler`.

My intention is to have a "generic" delegate such that when `OtherEvent` inherits the methods from `Event`, `OtherEvent` still has the flexibility to use its own type of delegate with different parameters from its parent for the `handler` class field.

What can I do to achieve my intention?

Comment: Does `OtherEventArgs` inherit from `EventArgs`?

Comment: @Rawling, Yes, `OtherEventArgs` inherit from `EventArgs`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe there are other ways to archive what you want.

Comment: @FelixK. This's my situation: I wrote an Event class. The Event class serves as the type of an event. So, when using it, I've to extend Event say, extend Event as ClickEvent, and ClickEvent is the type. I also have an EventManager that dispatches the Event. So, in this example, EventManager would dispatch ClickEvent. But within ClickEvent, when invoking the handlers, I may pass in a different EventArgs type from the other events. So in this same example, I'd pass in ClickEventArgs. Other events say MoveEvent may pass in MoveEventArgs. But problem is, the base class Event takes only EventArgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wrong with usage of default delegate [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx)? It can be parametrized with any type, inherited from `EventArgs`.

Also I don't really understand purpose of `Event` class. You can define events simply this way:

```
public event EventHandler<OtherEventArgs> OtherEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a generic instead of inheritance?

```
class Event<TEvent>
{
    TEvent _handler;
    public Event(TEvent handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }
}
```